# FragmentStatePagerAdapter duplicating Fragment's CursorLoader results

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-cursorloader, fragmentstatepageradapter

I am making a simple news application.

Its MainActivity contains a **ViewPager with TabLayout that hosts different fragments** for news categories.

The first two categories are Business (first) Sports (Second).

**The problem is that the content of these two fragments comes out to be same even though different loaders are used**, i.e. 'Business' tab shows Sports news.

But when you swipe 3rd fragment, the problem gets resolved. (Probably because ViewPager reloads the first fragment.)

The fragment has implemented Cursor Loader callbacks

`public class ArticleListFragment extends Fragment implements
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>`

In Fragment's `#onCreate`, I call the Loader:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
loader_id = bundle.getInt("id");
category = bundle.getString("category");
getLoaderManager().initLoader(loader_id, null, this);
}
```

Fragment's loader callbacks are as follows:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
    if(cursorLoader.getId() == loader_id){
        if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0)  {
            Log.i("haha","id: " + cursorLoader.getId());
            adapter.swapCursor(cursor);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    adapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

`MyPagerAdapter` has the following implementation of `getItem()`:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        ArticleListFragment fragment = ArticleListFragment.newInstance();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("category", categories.get(position));
        bundle.putInt("id",position);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }
```